# 画面行数よりもファイル行数が少ない場合に，上部にパディングを入れたい

Tags: vim

ターミナルの画面行数よりもファイル行数が少ない場合，通常は下部にパディングが入り，テキストは上部に寄せられます．
これを，上部にパディングを入れ，テキストを下部に寄せるように変更することはできるでしょうか？

### 意図

ディスプレイを縦設置してターミナルを全画面表示して使っているため，上端に表示されると見づらいため，下端に持ってきたいです．

### 現状

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 望む形（画像編集して作ったもの）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### :version

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar 25 2018 03:02:16)                                              
macOS version
Included patches: 1-1633
Compiled by travis@Traviss-Mac-913.local
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +dialog_con_gui    +job               +mouse_sgr         +ruby/dyn          +vertsplit
+arabic            +diff              +jumplist          -mouse_sysmouse    +scrollbind        +virtualedit
+autocmd           +digraphs          +kaoriya           +mouse_urxvt       +signs             +visual
-autoservername    +dnd               +keymap            +mouse_xterm       +smartindent       +visualextra
+balloon_eval      -ebcdic            +lambda            +multi_byte        +startuptime       +viminfo
+balloon_eval_term +emacs_tags        +langmap           +multi_lang        +statusline        +vreplace
+browse            +eval              +libcall           -mzscheme          -sun_workshop      +wildignore
++builtin_terms    +ex_extra          +linebreak         +netbeans_intg     +syntax            +wildmenu
+byte_offset       +extra_search      +lispindent        +num64             +tag_binary        +windows
+channel           +farsi             +listcmds          +odbeditor         +tag_old_static    +writebackup
+cindent           +file_in_path      +localmap          +packages          -tag_any_white     -X11
+clientserver      +find_in_path      +lua/dyn           +path_extra        -tcl               -xfontset
+clipboard         +float             +menu              +perl/dyn          +termguicolors     +xim
+cmdline_compl     +folding           +migemo            +persistent_undo   +terminal          -xpm
+cmdline_hist      -footer            +mksession         +postscript        +terminfo          -xsmp
+cmdline_info      +fork()            +modify_fname      +printer           +termresponse      -xterm_clipboard
+comments          +fullscreen        +mouse             +profile           +textobjects       -xterm_save
+conceal           +gettext           +mouseshape        +python/dyn        +timers
+cryptv            +guess_encode      +mouse_dec         +python3/dyn       +title
+cscope            -hangul_input      -mouse_gpm         +quickfix          +toolbar
+cursorbind        +iconv             -mouse_jsbterm     +reltime           +transparency
+cursorshape       +insert_expand     +mouse_netterm     +rightleft         +user_commands
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/macvim-kaoriya/HEAD-db0a1ad/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: /usr/bin/clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -I/usr/loc
al/Cellar/cmigemo-mk/HEAD-5c014a8/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/include -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -mmaco
sx-version-min=10.9 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: /usr/bin/clang   -L. -L/usr/local/lib -L. -L/usr/local/lib -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -headerpad_max_install_name
s -L/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.8.1/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurse
s -liconv -lintl -lmigemo -framework AppKit  -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000   -fstack-protector  -L/System/Li
brary/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE
```

Comment: 通常の編集時、入力した行数がまだ少ない時はパディングされているのではなく、「そこにまだ文字が入力されていない」という表示が (チルダで) されているだけのような気がします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

現状のVimでVimプラグイン使う使わないに関わらず要望を叶えることは出来ません。

Answer (score 0):

妥協案です。
ウィンドウ分割で下のウィンドウの高さを狭くして表示して、用が済んだら `:q` や `<C-W>q` 等で閉じるのはどうでしょうか？

```
:bot 2split
```

Comment: このコマンドだと，2行以上になっても表示されるのは1行だけなので，使いづらかったです．でも，上下分割は確かに有用で，上下同一サイズで分割する方法はやってみようと思います．